# How to define a generic anonymous function type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, anonymous-function

Is it possible to have Generic Anonymous function type?

I was reading this article and found [this piece of code](https://github.com/enricopolanski/functional-programming#:%7E:text=A%3E%20make%20sense%3F-,import%20%7B%20Eq%20%7D%20from%20%27fp%2Dts/Eq%27,-export%20const%20not).

```js
import { Eq } from 'fp-ts/Eq'

export const not = <A>(E: Eq<A>): Eq<A> => ({
  equals: (first, second) => !E.equals(first, second)
})
```

Is `not` function here even a valid typescript syntax?

Comment: Yup .. it's valid./. not sure what the question is: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgHgCoD4oF4oG8CwAoKKCOAVwEMAbAZwC4oAKAMzqQBooqIBjAewDsAJiwCUGNACMePChDJ98AX3z4IADzA8ATsCi8+VHXx47MCAIKsU9GHXjmUw24jNp0aergJFSlWg0YAlpoG7Jx6AqJuUACEMAB0xOTUTEEhHNz8EYrCQA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thank you. In your example in the playground you used comma in your generic type parameter `<A,>`. Without it it's seems to be a syntax error. What is that comma for?

Comment: In TSX files `<T>` is intrepreted as a JSX tag instead of a generic parmater list. The `,` forces it to be a generic parameter list. The playground works in TSX mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is perfectly fine ,

It's (almost) the equivalent of this generic function but with an arrow function definition :

```
function not2<A>(E: Eq<A>): Eq<A> {
  return {
    equals: function (first, second) {
       return !E.equals(first, second);
    }
  };
}
```